# Pass list into wilcox.test in R

Tags: database, r, statistics

I'm trying to pass all the numbers in a column of a dataframe to be analysed using `wilcox.test(·)` in R.

If I pass `c(1,2,3)` it works just fine, but I want to pass a column from a pre-existing database into the function without typing it out completely. (There are ~2million rows)

Passing the column gives the error : `'x' must be numeric.` 
(Understandably so)

Sample data:

```
    AA      AC       AD          AE         AF
 0.6047619  NA  -1.0000000   1.0059524  -1.000000
-0.2348790  NA   0.5812500   0.1294643  -1.000000
 0.9523810  -1  -1.0000000  -1.0000000  -1.000000
```

Statement used:

```
{print(wilcox.test(list, y = NULL, correct = TRUE, mu = 0, exact = NULL))}
```

Error message :

```
    Error in wilcox.test.default(list, y = NULL, correct = TRUE, mu = 0, exact = NULL) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

List is one column of the dataframe. From AA to 0.9523810.

Comment: Please include sample data and reproducible code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What is `list`? Your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a given column in a data frame named `df`, you can use one of the following:

```
df[1, ]     # by number: first column
df["x1", ]  # by name: column that is named "x1"
df$x1       # also by name
```

So in this case, you would use (if you wanted the column named "AA")

```
wilcox.test(df$AA, y=NULL, correct=TRUE, mu=0, exact=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `list` is your data frame, you can obtain the results for each column with the following:

```
apply(list,2,wilcox.test, y = NULL, correct = TRUE, mu = 0, exact = NULL)
```

You're getting an error because one of your columns is not a numeric variable.

Comment: I tried removing the first column using names(list). It didn't change anything, I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Are all of the columns in your dataframe numeric? It seems not. Find the ones that are not numeric and remove them and then this will work.